# become as well acquainted . . . as depended on

Tags: late-modern-english

The following is an extract from *Frankenstein* by Mary Shelley. I'd like to know whether the use of "as well . . . as" is natural in current English and what it means here.

> When I had arrived at this point, and had become **as well** acquainted with the theory and practice of natural philosophy **as** **depended** on the lessons of any of the professors at Ingolstadt, my residence there being no longer conducive to my improvements, I thought of returning to my friends and my native town,
> when an incident happened that protracted my stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes it is very much current.

> I'll get there as fast as I can

Probably said 100,000 times a day in the US.

> I'm as well now as I ever was.

But the piece of prose you are asking about is difficult to parse for at least three reasons. First, it is unusual to separate the first and last "as" by so many words. The mind loses track that we are in an "as ... as" construction. Second, the whole thing is verbose. Third, "acquainted" being dependent on lessons is a somewhat odd locution. (It may have been current during the early ninteenth century, but I cannot affirm or deny that.) What is meant is "learned."

Here is the meaning

> I had learned as much as I could about natural philosophy from the professors at Ingolstadt.

Comment: Would the original make more sense if rewritten as "When I had arrived at this point, and had become well acquainted with **as much** about the theory and practice of natural philosophy as depended on the lessons of any of the professors at Ingolstadt, my residence there . . ."?

Comment: I did not say that the original did not make sense. I said it was difficult to parse. Your suggested revision is clearer. I still feel that even your revision is unnecessarily verbose, but that is a stylistic opinion and thus personal..

Answer (score 1):

The "as ... as" correlative is natural and unremarkable in contemporary English.   The part that doesn't have currency is this reliance on a participial phrase.

A few reasonable paraphrasings might be:

> When I . . . had become as well acquainted with [these things] as *I could become from* the lessons . . . .
>
> When I . . . had become as well acquainted with [these things] as *might be derived from* the lessons . . . .
>
> When I . . . had become as well acquainted with [these things] as *relying on* the lessons . . . *could make me,* . . .

To a modern ear, it is odd to let a participle like "depended" carry as much semantic weight on its own as a finite predicate or even a complete clause might.

Comment: The "depended" in the original is not a participle, but a regular past-tense verb.

Comment: If it's finite, then what's its subject?

Comment: "as" is a quasi-relative pronoun, in the sense that it fulfills the function of subject as well. It's like the "as" in "such knowledge as may be derived from the lessons."

Comment: That this "may" is finite is a trivial discovery. That spelling must represent a finite form, and that verb is defective, lacking participles entirely. Knowledge may be derived. It's simpler to analyze that "as" as a preposition which licenses a predicate as its argument -- but even if we claim it to be a pronoun, "knowledge" is its antecedent. I have to ask again: what antecedent, what *referent*, can you find as the agent of a finite "depended"? I find none, as the concept involved is *a depended acquaintanceship*.  He was acquainted as well as [ [such] could be] depended on those lessons.

Comment: The antecedent of "as" as a quasi-relative pronoun is the  state of being well acquainted with the theory and practice of natural philosophy. The extent of that state depended on the lessons of the professors.

Comment: "He wanted to be the best husband he could be, to make Maria as happy as was humanly possible"

Comment: As a native speaker, I can recognize this "depended" as a participle because I can simply see that it carries no tense. Native speaker intuition shows me that the distinction between "as is depended" and "as was depended" is irrelevant to the original context.  Indeed, those options include semantics that the original lacks.  Since I suspect that this is not your native tongue, I'll suggest you compare your most recent example to the more natural "as happy as humanly possible", which contains neither tense nor verb.  But, you'll just have to take my word that the lack of tense is more natural.

Comment: You are not a native speaker of 19th-century English.

Comment: "After two years of unremitting and constant attention, the drawbench proved nearly as useful as was anticipated for silver, ..."

Comment: Since the past-tense of "depend" is homophonous with its past participle, you cannot assert "depended" carries no tense, let alone claim it is a participle.

Comment: This is why I dislike typological arguments. Typologies are more or less useful; they can never be right or wrong in an absolute sense. I think we all agree that the sentence inquired about sounds odd to the modern ear and deserves explication to a non-native speaker. I have read a fair bit of 18th and early 19th century British writing. My impression is that this is convoluted even by the standards of the prose of that era, but I shall defer to the judgment of anyone who has studied the prose styles of that ere in any depth.